# AS400 RPGLE Defining a display file in a module

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have been reading on creating modules and service programs in ILE, but I can't find much on defining a display window (prompt screen) inside a module.  I have tried the following, but keep getting an error that the RECNO parameter (RRN here) is not defined (*RNF7004).
Any idea what I am doing wrong....or where I can get more info...

```
    H NOMAIN                                                
    FWDWFACV   CF   E             WORKSTN                   
    F                                     SFILE(FACSFL:RRN) 
    FZMFL01    IF   E           K DISK                        
    D/COPY CUSSRCV6/QCPYSRC,TOOLS                           
    P WDWFAC          B                   EXPORT            
    DWDWFAC           PI                                    
    DWFAC                            2A                     
    DWFDESC                         20A   options(*nopass)  
    D RRN             S              3S 0 inz(0)            
    D WKFLAG          S              1S 0                   
    /free
```

Comment: What is SFLSIZ?  If larger than 999, perhaps that's the issue.  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fbooks_web%2Fc0925086321.htm  Define RRN as 4s 0 instead.

Answer (score 1):

The RRN variable, which is attached to the display file, probably needs to be global (defined outside the module).